# android list is getting 0 value in recyclerview when first run

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

hey guys my problem is my adapter list value is getting 0 value when i run my app for the first time. Then when i clicked the backpressed button and back again to my app its working fine. Im trying to display data from firebase.thanks for any help.

this is my userhelper class

```
public class UserHelper {
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private Context context;
private String success = "Add Success.";
private String error = "Something went wrong.";
private String message;
public UserHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    initFireBase();
}

private void initFireBase(){
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
}


public List<User> getData(){
    final List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference.child("User_table").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (list.size()>0)
                list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    list.add(user);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

}

then this is my mainactivity display code

```
@Override
public void displayData(List<User> list) {
    Adapter adapter= new Adapter(list, new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickItem(User user) {
            presenter.clickItem(user);
        }
    });
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: please add recyclerView adapter and initialization code

Comment: You need to call displayData inside the onDataChange callback. Otherwise it will return empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValueEventListener` is an asynchronous call . You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onDataChange`. The problem is your `getData()` is returned with blank list and the callback get called later. Change your methods as below :

```
 public void getData(){
    databaseReference.child("User_table").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                list.add(user);
            }
            displayData(list);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Handle error here
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void displayData(List<User> list) {
    Adapter adapter= new Adapter(list, new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickItem(User user) {
            presenter.clickItem(user);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```